# How to access database in phpmyadmin that connected to localhost using static ip address?

Tags: .htaccess, web, xampp, codeigniter-3

i'm developing web-based system information for my company.my boss asked me to use LAN. i'm using CodeIgniter, xampp and phpmyadmin. my web works good on localhost. then i did setting my ip address to static ip address, i editted my xampp configuration so that ip address that i have allowed could access my web. but the issue is the only page that everyone can access is the landing page. I can't access the other page that connect to the database such as the login function,etc. Anyone can help me with this issue?

i did the setting, such as editting the xampp configuration, allow all ip address, then i tried to access the ip addess, it works good on another PC while accessing the landing page. But when i clicked on the login button the next page didn't come up. it says the page said "this site can't be reached" also it said "checking proxy and the firewall.

I expect that user can access the login page also the database can automatically updated everytime user input data to the web.

Comment: You certainly do not want to grant access to the phpmyadmin database frontend, which only is for administrative tasks. Instead you have your code accessing that database, so your scripts. You will need to show the relevant parts of your scripts here. How else should we be able to help?

Comment: And the first thing you _always_ need to do when developing web applications: you need to monitor your http server's error log file. That is where runtime issues get logged to. That is where you can simply read what the current issue is. Note: _you cannot develop a web application without monitoring that file!_

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.